# R not producing any plots

Tags: graph, figure, gplots, sem

I downloaded the new update for R (4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)) and for some reason, it isn't producing any of my previously made plots. Example below.

corPlot(ucla_val)

semPlot::semPaths(UCLA_8, what = "std", layout = "circle")

I'll save them to variables and it produces a table of numbers I need but not the plots.

Please help!

I've tried re-installing the packages, with dependancies, and Restarting R. I'm just short of uninstalling and re-installing R (which may be my last option).

Edit: my packages and R are installing in different places.